# event stop propagation issue with children event

Tags: jquery, stoppropagation

I have an issue with jquery stop propagation.
To close a cart modal when i click on the page except on the cart modal, i had to do :

```
        $('html').click(function() {
            $('.cart-block').css('display','none');
        });

        $('.mycart, .cart-block').click(function(event){
            event.stopPropagation();

        });
```

But i have an issue, i have an AJAX call to delete an item inside my cart div (cart-block) but the stop propagation is stopping the event.

```
$(document).on('click', '.deleteItem', function() {
    //ajax call
});
```

Is anyone can help me ?
thanks a lot
(sorry for my english)

EDIT : HTML STRUCTURE 
//button cart

```
  <div class="center cart mycart" >
           //icon and cart item counter
            </div>

        <div id="cartcaption" class="cart-block">
    //modal : content of the cart
<div class="productsPanier">
 <span id="{{$cart->rowId}}" class="deleteItem">delete</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you please show the structure of your HTML?

Comment: Yes, i updated the post, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of what you're doing (binding 2 handlers with one stopping propagation), just bind one handler and check whether the target of event has class .cart-block

So something like this:

```
$('html').click(function(event) {
   if (!$(event.target).hasClass('cart-block'))
      $('.cart-block').css('display','none');
});
```

And remove the following part

```
 $('.mycart, .cart-block').click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
 });
```

Your events will now properly propagate and the 'display: none;' won't get added to cart block if you're clicking within cart-block element

EDIT: if the outermost class is named 'mycart', you could alternatively try it like this:

```
$('html').click(function(event) {
   if (!($(event.target).closest('.mycart').length))
      $('.cart-block').css('display','none');
});
```

What this will do is check if the target element of your click has a parent with class 'mycart'. This solution assumes that whatever you click inside the cart has a container with class 'mycart'. Obviously, without seeing your DOM, I cannot be sure this will solve your specific case. If it's different to what I assumed, it should point you in the right direction at least.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it doesn't work because if you click inside the cart on another class it close the cart.

Comment: See my edit. This will work for everything so long as you always click on a child of 'mycart' (meaning all of the clickable area is actually a child of the 'mycart' container). If you have some parts of the 'mycart' that can be clicked directly (ie, when clicking on them, the event target is 'mycart' and not a child of 'mycart', then you'll have to add the 'or' handling within the if statement.

Comment: i just had to add the both class .closest('.mycart, .cart-block'), one for the cart button and one for the cart modal

Comment: Sorry, didn't see the DOM you posted before. Yeah, as the .cart-block is not a child of the .mycart div, that's the way to go, in my answer I assumed that it was a child. No problem ;)
If the issue is resolved with this, please mark the answer as useful